# Check if List has empty strings in Groovy

Tags: groovy

In Groovy, I am taking the values from a Map and creating a List from this. I then want to check if that List (of values) is empty.

My whole aim is to check if ALL the values of `myMap` are blank or empty.

In the code below, the values of `myMap` will either be an empty string or have some value.

```
Map myMap = [:]
myMap["a"] = "$A"
myMap["b"] = "$B"
myMap["c"] = "$C"

List myList = myMap.values() //[, , , ]
```

`myList` returns `[, , , ]`. How do I check this List contains all empty strings or do I go about this a whole other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Use `every`

```
myList.every { it == '' }
```

To check if any of them are `''`, use `any`

```
myList.any { it == '' }
```

Comment: Be careful with `every`. It returns `true` on an empty list, regardless of the closure, which kind of defeats the purpose. They seem to think it's ok: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7207

Answer (score 0):

In brief, just check if the list contains non-empty string.  If so, it is not non-empty.

pseudo-code:

```
boolean isEmptyStringList(list) {
    foreach stringVal in list {
        if stringVal != "" {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

I believe you can make it one-liner using Groovy language features (like `list.findAll{var != ""} > 0` ? not very familiar with Groovy :P ) but the above code should be a good starting point for programming beginner